# PyCharm: After each word is typed, there is a delay where one is unable to type

Tags: python, pycharm, delay

In PyCharm (JetBrains), I have been having trouble with typing full statements without getting an interuption. I first thought it was due to me not having updated the software, so I updated it, but the problem remains.

So if I type any statement or word, PyCharm seems to delay before I can proceed. An example:

```
import csv
```

Even before I finish typing "import" - if I delay a keystroke - PyCharm begins to "think" and the window is not accessible for about one to two seconds (quite literally). I assume it is going to give me suggestions or show a tip/error about the code.

Any thoughts to prevent this from happening?

Edit:

- Windows 8.1; PyCharm 2016.2
- Code Complete turned off via Settings->Editor->General->Code Completion, but did not solve problem.
- Key PC Spec:

  - Intel Core i5-337U
  - 4GB Ram
  - 64-bit

Edit2:
I receive this error when I run anything now, including simply print("test"): 
Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)
Will separate the question somewhere else, since this may be a separate problem altogether.

Comment: What OS are you using? I am using PyCharm for a year now on Ubuntu, and nothing like this ever happened.

Comment: Win7 here with no issues as well. Is your setup a very low-end one?

Comment: Windows 8.1. I wouldn't say it is too low end and it should be able to take care of these kinds of things. I can run other programs that have far more requirements.

Comment: Same issue here. I'm the only one on my team that it happens too. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: I have to admit, I do nto recall how I solved the problem, but I believe it had to do with the second edit I made. Sorry to say I do not have a good answer. I also changed machines recently so the problem doesn't exist with this machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling code completion. I believe that your computer can't search through all of Python's librarys fast enough so it freezes for a bit.

Comment: I tried to completely disabled and restarted PyCharm, but unfortunately no luck.